# algebraic distance of an element of a ring from an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal. Does there exist a notion of "distance" of an element $x \in A$ from the ideal $I$? This "distance", need not be of the form $A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; it could be an algebraic construction, perhaps in terms of exact sequences and resolutions or even a topological construction.

Any ideas?

Are there any related theories?

Edit: Lets consider the more specific case where $A=\mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and $I$ is an ideal of $A$. Let $f(x) \in A$ be a polynomial. Then i am interested in a mechanism that would allow me to determine how close $f(x)$ is to $I$ and then possibly find the element of $I$ that is closest to $f(x)$.

Comment: You can endow an algebraic variety, which is nicer than a commutative ring, with a topology known as the Zarinski topology. However, it looks like (from the internet) that this is not a metrizable space. Thus my intuition suggests that there is no metric that would work here.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: We can endow a commutative ring with the Zariski topology as well. Also, why is an algebraic variety nicer than a commutative ring?

Comment: @FrankMcGovern The most convincing way to remember that the Zariski topology isn't metrizable is because it is (almost) always not Hausdorff.

Comment: I have little experience with the Zariski* (whoops) topology, and I was going more on internet-ing than real experience with algebraic geometry.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: No problem! Thanks for the interest in my question, anyway :)

Comment: @Manos I'm really curious if such a distance exists! I'm thinking of trying to impose a Cayley-graph-esque structure using the ideal as a generator, though I don't have time to work it out right now ...

Comment: Related: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/almost+scheme

Comment: I very quickly got a [googlebooks](http://books.google.com/books?id=_CYY-5ETxlYC&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=metrizable+ring&source=bl&ots=IXLCLPzb-r&sig=eo8iTx5Ezxow3d8UCewj8oX4C-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XG5HUfSVAebmyQHsl4Bg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=metrizable%20ring&f=false) hit which talks about metrizable rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ideas off the top of my head.  Is there something specific you want to do with such a construction?  (**EDIT:** I just saw your edit.  I'm not sure how well any of what I said applies, but maybe it'll help inspire you.  I'll think more about your question and get back to you.)

First, you can form the ideal $(I:x) = \{y \in A: xy \in I\}$.  A larger colon ideal seems to suggest that $x$ is multiplicatively 'closer to $I$'.  If $x \in I$, this is all of $A$; if $I$ is prime and $x \not\in I$, it's equal to $I$.  My favorite application of this is the [Lam-Reyes Prime Ideal Principle](http://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/JAlg-PIP.pdf), which lets you conclude that ideals maximal with respect to certain properties are always prime.

Second, there's a natural topology on $A$ called the [$I$-adic topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_%28ring_theory%29).  This has a basis given by the sets $x + I^n$ for $x \in A$ and $n \ge 0$.  This is Hausdorff iff $\bigcap I^n = 0$, and in this case it's metrizable, with metric given by (for example) $d(x,y) = 2^{-n}$ if $x \in y + I^n$ but not $y + I^{n+1}$.  The thing people most commonly do with this (particularly when $A$ is local with maximal ideal $I$) is to form the completion, which actually carries a ring structure: it's just $\varprojlim A/I^n$.

In case that's too abstract, here's a good example: take $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I$  a prime ideal $(p)$.  Then the distance of $x$ from $0$ (its '$p$-adic absolute value') measures how many factors of $p$ are in $x$, with numbers that are highly divisible by $p$ being very close to zero.  The completion is the limit of the inverse system $\dotsb \to \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  That is, to give an element of this ring, you first pick an integer $a_1$ mod $p$; then an integer $a_2$ mod $p^2$ that reduces to $a_1$ mod $p$; and so on.  Since high powers of $p$ are small, the successive $a_i$ are like increasingly close approximations to the element you want.  (This completion is called the '$p$-adic integers' $\mathbb{Z}_p$.)

The Zariski topology, as Frank McGovern mentioned in his comment, is actually a topology on the *set of prime ideals* of the ring $A$, though it's still the best way to think about $A$ as a topological space.  This topological space carries a natural 'structure sheaf,' and elements of $A$ are best thought of in this context as global sections of this sheaf.  (Depending on your background, that last sentence will either be obvious or make no sense.  If the latter, look at an introductory book on algebraic geometry, like [Ravi Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/).)

Comment: Excellent answer, too bad i can upvote only once. The $I$-dic topology seems particularly intriguing!

Comment: Thanks!  The problem is that it's really telling you how deep $x$ is inside $I$, rather than how far away $x$ is from $I$.  Which is roughly the opposite of what you want.

Comment: I was considering writing up the $I$-adic suggestion but when I saw it was "the opposite" of what we wanted, I didn't bother :) Maybe you can make use of the idea without it being a full metric?

Comment: I could potentially get inspiration from anything. What you have written is already interesting. Two questions regarding Ravi Vakil's notes: 1) I took a quick look and looks like similar to Hartshorne. I am completely wrong? 2) In page 12 the author writes: "We allow nilpotents in the ring of functions, which is basically analysis (looking at near-solutions of equations instead of exact solutions)." What does he mean by that?

Comment: I take back the comment about Hartshorn. Vakil's notes seem much more friendly :)

Comment: The main problem I have with Hartshorne is that it starts with varieties as 'motivation', but then abandons all pretext of motivation as soon as it starts doing schemes, precisely when motivation is most needed!  It also seems a little less useful if you're more interested in e.g. arithmetic geometry than varieties, which I'd wager is true for a lot of people who read that book.  Vakil starts you out in the language of schemes and has an EGA-ish table of contents, but there's always enough intuition to get you used to the language.

Comment: Re nilpotents: I'm not totally sure, but one way people think about it is as follows.  Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.  If $X = \mathrm{Spec} k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I$ is an affine variety over $k$, then giving a function on $X$ is the same as giving one on $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ but only caring about its values at the points of $X$.  If we now allow $X$ to have nilpotents in its ring, functions on $X$ contain slightly more information than just values at its points, and I guess you could think of this as 'analytical'.

Comment: (cont'd) For example, if $X = \mathrm{Spec}\, k[x]/(x^2)$, then a function on $X$ is something of the form $a + bx$, but $0$ is the only point of $X$.  Restricting a function from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to $X$ tells you its value at $0$ but also its first derivative in the $x$ direction.  For this reason, $X$ is also drawn as a point with a tangent vector sticking out.  Likewise you could have schemes that capture second-order information at a point and so on (Spec of a completion will give you the Taylor series!)  Eisenbud and Harris's *Geometry of Schemes* is a good place to learn about this stuff.